# ACTK Modal Popup's background disappears after scrolling up and down several time

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

AJAX Control ToolKit Modal Popup's background (the blind curtain) disappears after scrolling up and down several times. I've tried using the following CSS styles but still no luck.

```
.modalBackground
{
    filter:alpha(opacity=70);
    padding-left: 0px;
    background-color:Gray;         
        color: #000000;
        vertical-align: top;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        padding-top: 0px;
 }

.modalBackgroundV2
{
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 100;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            background-color: #000;
            filter: alpha(opacity=60);
            -moz-opacity: 0.6;
            opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not had any problem when using the following CSS styles

```
.modalBackground
{
   background-color:Gray;
   filter:alpha(opacity=70);
   opacity:0.7;
}
```